# Can't inflate layout properly for a fragment in Android application

Tags: android, textview, fragment, layout-inflater

In first place this is the code of the fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private View FragmentView;

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        MyFragment NewFragment = new MyFragment();
        return NewFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.tasks, 
            new LinearLayout(MainActivity.MainContext)
        );
        FragmentView.setLayoutParams(
            new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
        );
        addText();

        return FragmentView;
    }

    private void addText() {
        TasksView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_image);
        TextView MyTitle = new TextView(MainActivity.MainContext);
        MyTitle.setLayoutParams(
            new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
        );

        MyTitle.setText(R.string.mytitle);
        ((LinearLayout) FragmentView).addView(MyTitle );
    }
}
```

`MainActivity.MainContext` is stored as `public static` in the main activity's class and is retrieved when creating the activity by `getApplicationContext()`.

Now, the problem lays here:

```
 FragmentView = inflater.inflate(
     R.layout.tasks, 
     new LinearLayout(MainActivity.MainContext)
 );
```

Because of this, the `MyTitle` text view is not displayed inside the fragment. If I do this:

```
FragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks, null);
```

it is displayed but I get a warning:

```
Avoid passing null as the view root (needed to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element)
```

I would like do it properly and not get any warnings and I don't find a way. I also tried:

```
FragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks, container);
```

but the application crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass `container` as a parent.

```
FragmentView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.tasks, 
            container,
            false
        );
```

Also you should specify `false`, so `LayoutInflater` does not attach the inflated view to parent. The inflated view is attached to parent by `FragmentManager`.

Comment: For more info on why a null parent is bad, see: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I tried to add a new textview in the same way (after the first one) but I only see the first one. Any idea?